# Kafka Consumer get assigned partitions for a specific topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm working with a Kafka Consumer, and only subscribe to one topic.  I want to return only the assigned partitions from the topic for each consumer.  I am running  four instances of the consumer in the same group, and reading a topic with 8 partitions.

I know I can use the assignment() method, but it looks like that returns the topic name and partition in the format of - (i.e. topic1-0, topic1-1, etc).  Is there a better way of getting the partition only without having to parse the value returned from the assignment() method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**public `Set<TopicPartition>` assignment()**

`assignment()` will  return the set of `TopicPartition`

**public int partition()** . [here](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/TopicPartition.html)

In the `TopicPartition` you have method `partition()` that gives the partition of topic

**Example**

```
Set<TopicPartition> partitions = consumer.assignment();
partitions.forEach(part->System.out.println(part.partition()));
```

Comment: Thanks Deadpool.  That did exactly what I needed.